# C Delete Linked List By Reference?

Tags: c, list, linked-list

Brand new to C, tried other SO Answers that I found about this before posting, and saw that none of them were using a function and passing their list in by reference for deleting all item, but that is the way I want to implement it.  Console is outputting

> *** Error in `./testing': double free or corruption (out): 0x00007ffc26622b30 *** Aborted

Awesome error message for a noob! That isn't cryptic at all. :)
P.S. All of my other functions are working as intended.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

typedef struct node
{
    int n;
    struct node* next;
} 
node;

bool search(int number, node* list);
void showItems(node* list);
void insertItem(int number, node** list);
void deleteItem(int number, node** list);
void deleteList(node** list);

int main(void)
{

    node* list = NULL;

    insertItem(1337, &list);
    insertItem(1337, &list);

    bool found = search(5, list);
    if (found)
    {
        printf("found number in linked list.");
    }

    deleteList(&list);

    showItems(list);
}

void showItems(node* list)
{
    node* ptr = list;
    while (ptr)
    {
        printf("%i\n",ptr->n);
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
}

bool search(int number, node* list)
{
    node* ptr = list;
    while (ptr)
    {
        if (ptr->n == number)
        {
            return true;
        }
        ptr = ptr->next;

    }
    //Number not found.
    return false;
}

void insertItem(int number, node** list)
{
    node* newItem = malloc(sizeof(node));
    newItem->n = number;
    newItem->next = *list;
    *list = newItem;
}

void deleteItem(int number, node** list)
{

    node* ptr = *list;
    node* prev = NULL;

    while (ptr)
    {
        if (ptr->n == number)
        {
            if (prev != NULL)
            {
                //Check if there is a previous node.  If there is, set its next node to the current items next node.  Then free the current node.
                prev->next = ptr->next;

            }
            free(ptr);
            break;
        }
        prev = ptr;
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
}

void deleteList(node** list)
{
    node* temp = NULL;
    while (list)
    {
        temp = *list;
        free(list);
        list = &temp->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) `while (list)` : infinite loop. 2) `deleteList(&list); showItems(list);` --> `showItems(list); deleteList(&list);`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY list is being set to &temp->next at the end of each iteration, eventually temp->next will be == NULL, breaking from the loop....

Comment: `temp->next` will be `== NULL`, but `&temp->next != NULL`

Comment: 3) `free(list);` maybe can't `free`'d

Comment: @BLUEPIXY free(list) would only free the head, it would not iterate over the list and free each item???

Comment: note : type of `list` is `node**`. You mean `head`, probably `*list`.

Comment: maybe, You want `while(*list){ temp = *list; list = &temp->next; free(temp);}`

Comment: or `while(*list){ temp = *list; *list = temp->next; free(temp);}` (Probably this intended behavior.)

Comment: C doesn't support references and is strictly pass-by-value.

Comment: @Olaf I've heard what you say is correct, but it is possible to change a variable thats been passed into a function, and have that change persist after the function has exited?  Not just have the byval copy changed.  You can probably see that is my goal here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A better solution would look something like this:

```
while(*list) {
  node* tmp = (*list)->next;
  free(*list);
  *list = tmp;
}
```

Your solution stores the address of the node pointed to by `list`, then frees what you never alloc'd - you attempt to free a `node**`, but you only alloc `node`s. After doing that, you then try to dereference the memory that you just (sorta) tried to free.

You need to store a pointer to the next node, free the current node, and then move onto the next node.

Comment: Tried implementing your solution, compiler says "testing.c:100:26: error: member reference base type 'node *' (aka 'struct node *') is not a structure or union"

Comment: I edited my answer somewhat. It's not an exact implementation and was meant more as some pseudocode.

It should work perfectly now. I forgot that `list` was a `node**` at first when I wrote my answer.

Comment: Your edited answer worked perfectly!

Comment: No problem! I hope it makes sense why it works that way.

I TA a data structures course, so I can go somewhat more in depth as to why/how it works if you need.

Comment: The one part that I am having a bit of trouble with is (*list)->next, I wasn't aware of the this type of syntax, what is it doing exactly when I put *list in the parenthesis?

Comment: When you pass the `list` in by reference to the function with the `&` operator, you're passing a pointer to it (a `node**`). You have to dereference it first (`(*list)`) before you can use the `->` operator to access its `next` variable.

The `->` operator itself is actually just shorthand - `node->next` is equivalent to `(*node).next`. `(*list)->next` is the same as `(*(*list)).next`.

Comment: Ok that is a nice way of explaining it thanks.  For some reason I had thought &list-> would be equivalent (*list)->, but obviously it isn't because it won't compile.  Not really sure how I had that idea in my head, oh well :\  I feel like when I moved on to pointers of pointers, I just got extra confused..

Comment: That can happen! The `&` operator is for getting the address of something - think of it as the inverse of the `*` operator.

The `&` operator returns a pointer to the variable you call it on; the `*` operator dereferences a pointer you give it.

Answer (score 1):

For a noob, this is good coding. But I have seen some flaw.

First, in function "deleteItem" you check if (prev != NULL) but you do nothing when it's NULL. You have to update *list.

```
    if (prev != NULL)
    {
        //Check if there is a previous node.  If there is, set its next node to the current items next node.  Then free the current node.
        prev->next = ptr->next;
    } 
    else // you have to add an else here
    {
        *list = ptr->next;
    }
```

Then, in the function "deleteList", I see three misteakes.

- you test list, but "list" is a pointer on a pointer. The pointer is "*list"
- you use the memory after you called free()
- you free list, but here again the pointer is "*list"

  ```
  node* temp = NULL;
  while (list)
  {
      temp = *list;
      free(list);
      list = &temp->next;
  }
  ```

You can write something like:

```
    while (*list)
    {
        node *temp = (*list)->next;
        free(*list);
        *list = temp;
    }
```

Comment: You are right, but it's the same answer as Chris above.  Still, I appreciate you taking the time to help me out.  The else part I didn't have so I upvoted you.